# While loop for alphabet

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to code the following example.

```
Input  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Output  ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

If user types in `A` it will output `Z`.  It has to go past 25 characters to reach `Z`. So I am guessing a while loop will be needed, then if `B` it has to go through 23 times, so – 2 and so on until it reaches `M` as it will skip though 1 to reach `N`, then start again at 25.

Any suggestion on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

Capital `ASCII` characters range according to the ASCII-table from 65 (`0x41`, '`A`') to 90 (`0x5A`, '`Z`').

This is the algorithm:

```
// inputChar is a char holding your character
char inputChar = getCharFromUser();
int inputVal = inputChar - 65; // e.g. 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B'
char outputChar = 90 - inputVal; // e.g. 90 - 1 = 89 = 'Y' 
outputCharToUser(outputChar);
```

And this is how you might implement it in C#:

```
while (true)
{
    var key = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
    var inputChar = char.ToUpper(key.KeyChar);
    var outputChar = (char)('Z' - inputChar + 'A');
    Console.Write("{0}={1} ", inputChar, outputChar);
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `C#`.

Comment: the language tag says C#

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. should work with c# i guess?

Comment: You can write instead of 3th and 4th lines `char outputChar = 'Z' + 'A' - inputChar;`

Comment: Or you could reduce this to `char outputChar = 155 - inputChar;`

Comment: @juharr I mean, `'Z' + 'A'  - inputChar` describes the algorithm better.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko I agree, I was just giving another option.

Answer (score 3):

You could use two dictionaries which enable to lookup the char from index and vice-versa:

```
var indexLookup = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    .Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.chr, x => x.index);
var charLookup = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    .Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.chr);
```

Now it's simple, the essential part is `charLookup[25 - indexOfChar]`:

```
string userInput = "B";

bool isUpper = char.IsUpper(userInput[0]);
char inputChar = Char.ToLowerInvariant(userInput[0]);
if(indexLookup.ContainsKey(inputChar))
{
    int indexOfChar = indexLookup[inputChar];
    char oppositeChar = charLookup[25 - indexOfChar];
    string result = isUpper ? Char.ToUpperInvariant(oppositeChar).ToString() : oppositeChar.ToString();
    Console.Write(result); // Y
}
```

---

Actually you don't need two dictionaries but only one since the `string` can already be used to lookup a char by index. Here is a class which provides the logic:

```
public class CharSwap
{
    private string alphabet;
    private Dictionary<char, int> indexLookup;

    public CharSwap() : this("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") { }
    public CharSwap(string alphabet)
    {
        if(alphabet == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("alphabet");
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
        indexLookup = alphabet.Select((chr, index) => new { chr, index }).ToDictionary(x => x.chr, x => x.index);
    }

    public char? OppositeChar(char input)
    {
        char lowerChar = Char.ToLowerInvariant(input);
        if (!indexLookup.ContainsKey(lowerChar))
            return null;
        int indexOfChar = indexLookup[lowerChar];
        int indexOpposite = alphabet.Length - 1 - indexOfChar;
        return Char.IsUpper(input) 
            ? Char.ToUpperInvariant(alphabet[indexOpposite])
            : alphabet[indexOpposite];
    }
}
```

Test:

```
CharSwap cw = new CharSwap();
char? oppositeChar = cw.OppositeChar('B');
Console.Write(oppositeChar);
```

Comment: Why use 2 dictionaries when you only need one? check out my answer. I've borrowed the isUpper idea from your you, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: yes, i think one dictionary is sufficient. I just wanted to show that often two lookups help to simplify a requirement. What if the logic changes? But your approach needs currently even three collections and has an issue if the char is unknown.

Comment: It needs 3 collections since I'm now only starting with Linq. I'm guessing there is some linq method to create the dictionary directly from the string (I've tried to play a little with your .Select but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted). As for the unknown char, I've edited my answer to throw the appropriate exception

Comment: @ZoharPeled: there's another option, you can use the string like a dictionary. Added similar approach to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
 char[] alphabet = {'A','B', 'C'} // and so on
 char[] mapsTo = {'Z', 'Y', 'X'} // and so on, excluded for brevity
 public function string changeLetter(char input)
 {
   int i = 0;
   foreach (char c in alphabet) {
      if (c == input) {
       return mapsTo[i];
      }
     i++;
   }
   return '';
 }
```

Converted to c#:

```
char[] alphabet = {'A','B', 'C'}; // and so on
char[] mapsTo = {'Z', 'Y', 'X'}; // and so on, excluded for brevity
public string changeLetter(char input)
{
   int i = 0;
   foreach (char c in alphabet) {
      if (c == input) {
       return mapsTo[i].ToString();
      }
     i++;
   }
   return default(char).ToString();
}
```

You would call this function like this (for instance):

```
public static void RunProgram()
{
 Console.WriteLine("Please type in character");
 input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
 Console.WriteLine("You typed in " + input + ". This results in: " + ChangeInput(input));
}
```

... where "ChangeInput" is the function defined earlier.

Comment: @SonerGönül while it is not C# - it is kind of *suggestion* OP asked for.

Comment: I've updated my question a bit to be more C#. What is this logic error? I don't see it.

Comment: @StevenLemmens You fixed the error.  It was actually more of a compilation error than a logic error as you were missing a curly bracket and the return statement.

Comment: @juharr: ah yes I did thix those in my edit as well. I was just about to start up a quick project to see if my code would work or not :-)

Comment: could you test this, I am running but generates a few errors

Comment: @StevenLemmens I've edited your question and added your function converted to proper c#.

Comment: I am trying -    Console.WriteLine("Please type in character");
        input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.ReadLine();  after the last line return  but get an error - unreachable code detected?

Comment: You can't type anything after the return statement, as the function actually ends right there. So I would suggest putting the Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadKey().KeyChar outside of the function and calling the function with the input.

Comment: Could you give an example in terms of calling the function, eg user types in 'A'

Answer (score 1):

```
char input = 'B';
string Range = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char result = Range[Range.Length - 1 - Range.IndexOf(input)]; //Y
```

or maybe another approach

```
char input = 'B';
string Range = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char result = Range.Reverse().ElementAt(Range.IndexOf(input)); //Y
```

Comment: nice piece of code, could you explain why it is - 1?

Comment: when you have a array with 1 item - the index of the first item equals `0` but the length = `1`

Comment: I understand that, but to get from A-Z, its 25?

Comment: for A to get to Z it needs to jump 25 places, then B - Y 23

Comment: yes when you type 'A' then my method picks `Range[26-1-0]` because we have 26 elements and A has index 0, when you type 'B' my method picks `Range[26-1-1]`

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this is to use a `Dictionary<char, char>`:

```
public class Atbash {

    static string source = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static List<char> keys = source.ToList();
    static List<char> values = source.Reverse().ToList();
    static Dictionary<char, char> Converter = keys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => values[keys.IndexOf(x)]);


    public static char Convert(char input)
    {
        char output;
        bool isUpper = char.IsUpper(input);
        input = char.ToLowerInvariant(input);
        if(Converter.ContainsKey(input)) {
            output =  Converter[input];
            return (isUpper) ? char.ToUpperInvariant(output) : output;
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Input char is unknown");
        // of course, it can return default(char) instead of throwing an exception.
    }

}
```

Why Atbash? [read about it here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash)